# Separate Admin,User Area in Angular with different style and js layout

Tags: angular

as the title shows the question
I want to create the project with 2 complete separate layouts the user side and admin panel with completely deferent CSS js and HTML layout

I saw this video 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FNtN3rfq1UI

and saw this code

https://stackblitz.com/github/jbojcic1/angular-routing-example/tree/routing-reuse-layout-example-2-with-lazy-loaded-modules?file=src%2Fstyles.css

but the problem that I have here is that angular has its default layout HTML
the index.html in the src folder
and styles.css, js for import global CSS js

but I want to work with this layout like what we do in asp MVC views?

how can I do that without going to completely separate admin/user to separate angular project

**update**

this answer is good

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-multi-layout-example
https://angular-multi-layout-example.stackblitz.io

but for example, I want the app-layout in layout folder to import the css and js globally I mean the dashboard component that is a child for app-layout  had that js CSS

Comment: What's the issue with the example you provided? Does exactly what you need. You only need 1 `index.html` which is required by angular for bootstrapping and have angular handle all the routing. You don't need to use `style.css` you can just provide your own through `assets` although it's preferable if you do your css in component level for encapsulation. As for JS, most of the time you don't need it, packages are usually enough unless you are heavily relying on 3rd party javascript that's not available on npm.

Comment: @penleychan  exactly heavily relying on 3rd party javascript so how can I do that U know that the global css js only can importi9n index.html